# PDE: A priori estimate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \textbf{R}^N$ be open and bounded. Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and let
$u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be a weak solution of the equation
\begin{align}
Lu \equiv - \sum_{i,j=1}^n D_i(a_{ij}D_ju) = f. \tag{1}
\end{align}
This is defined by
\begin{align}
    \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}D_i u D_j v ~dx = \int_{\Omega}fv~dx
    \tag{2}
\end{align}
for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Suppose that there is a constant $\Theta > 0$
such that for all $x \in \Omega$
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{
    \sum_{i,j = 1}^n (a_{ij}(x))^2
    }
    \leq \Theta.
    \tag{3}
\end{align}
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\textbf{R}^n$ this also implies that
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x) \zeta_i \xi_j \leq \Theta |\zeta| |\xi|
    \tag{4}
\end{equation}
for all $x \in \Omega$ and all $\zeta, \xi$ in $\textbf{R}^n$.
Let us furthermore assume that there is a constant $\theta > 0$ s.t.
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_{ij}(x)\xi_i \xi_j \geq \theta |\xi|^2
    \tag{5}
\end{align}
for all $x \in \Omega$ and $\xi \in \textbf{R}^n$.

Let $\eta \in C^1_c(\Omega)$ be arbitrary. Prove the following a priori estimate:
There holds
\begin{align}
    \int_{\Omega}|Du|^2\eta^2dx 
    \leq C_0 
    \left (
    \int_{\Omega}u^2(|D\eta|^2 + \eta^2)dx +
    \int_U f^2\eta^2 dx
    \right )
    \tag{*}
\end{align}
where $C_0$ depends only on $\theta$ and $\Theta$.

The first step here is to use $v = u \eta^2$ and plug it into the definition of the weak solution which is stated in equation $(2)$. The next step would be to use Cauchy-Schwarz and Peter-Paul together
with the above conditions on $(a_{ij})$, but this is the point where im currently stuck.
I would be really happy if someone could help me out!

Cheers, Pinch

Comment: After setting $v=u\eta^2$ use chain rule to be able to apply (5) to obtain the term on the left of (*).

Comment: What is Peter-Paul?

Comment: In addition to what @daw said, simply apply Young's inequality several times for the different terms and subtract one part in the lefthandside. Hope that helps